# Using change of variables to transform density functions

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, change-of-variable, gamma-distribution

I'm was working on some exercises on statistical inference and came across a question I could not solve. After a while I decided to take a look at the solution to hopefully understand the problem better.

**Situation:** Let $X_{1} \dots X_{n}$ be independent and identically distributed random variables, each with the $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution. We have that $\mu \in\mathbb{R}$ is a known parameter and $\sigma^2$ is unknown. We consider $T=\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=i}(X_{i}-\bar{X})^{2}}{n-1}$ and can use the fact that $\frac{(n-1)}{\sigma^2} T\sim Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

**My problem:** In the solution is the following line:

> Since $T=cY$, where $c=\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}$ and $Y\sim
> Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, using a change of variables yields
>   that $f_{T}(x)=c^{-1}f_{Y}(x/c)$.

How does this change of variables work? How is it computed and why is it even necessary? Is it because the distribution of $T$ itself isn't explicitly given, but rather the distribution of $cT$? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this as a simple change of variable in an integral:

$$ P(T < t) = P(cY < t) = P(Y < \frac{t}{c}) =\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{t}{c}} f^Y(x)dx  $$

define $ u = cx \Rightarrow " du = c dx"  \iff dx "=" \frac{1}{c}du.$

This yields

$$ P(T< t) =  \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{t}{c}} f^Y(x)dx  = \int_{-\infty}^t \frac{1}{c} f^Y(u/c) du .$$

And $c^{-1}f^Y(xc^{-1})$ is a probability density function for $T$.

Comment: The originial exercise was about computing the Fisher information based on $T$, i.e. $I_{T}(\sigma^2)$. Is this step necessary because we only know the distribution of $cT$ and not $T$? Or is there another reason for having to change the variables?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to help you with that,  I'm not very gifted when it comes to computing Fischer information. I'm also not familiar with the concept of calculating the fisher information based on a given statistic $T$. :(

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Hope I can revive this question. Shouldn't there be a $t/c$ as the upper boundary of your last integral in the last line? If not, why did it turn into a $t$?

Comment: @S.Crim By using the substitution $u = cx$ then $u$ is a function of $x$ and we can write it as $u(x) = cx$. Then when $x$ approches $-\infty$ then so does $u$ since $c > 0$. When $x  = \frac{t}{c}$ then $u = u(\frac{t}{c}) = c \cdot \frac{t}{c} = t.$